# SonarQube cannot parse Pylint output

Tags: python, sonarqube, pylint

I'm trying to feed a Pylint analysis report into sonarQube.

Call to sonar-scanner is:

```
sonar-scanner -X -Dsonar.python.pylint.reportPath=report.txt ...
```

where *report.txt* is Pylint "vanilla" output formatting and looks like:

```
************* Module src.module.file
src/module/file.py:200:13: W0511: TODO fix it
src/module/file.py:49:0: W0622: Redefining built-in 'ConnectionError' (redefined-builtin)
```

And all I get is sonar complaining:

```
17:27:39.330 DEBUG: Cannot parse the line: ************* Module src.module.file
17:27:39.330 DEBUG: Cannot parse the line: src/module/file.py:200:13: W0511: TODO fix it
17:27:39.330 DEBUG: Cannot parse the line: src/module/file.py:49:0: W0622: Redefining built-in 'ConnectionError' (redefined-builtin)
```

I'm using sonar-scanner 4.4.0 and Pylint 2.11.1.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK it turns out sonar-scanner cannot parse "vanilla" Pylint output.
As stated [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/external-issues/), Pylint output should be formatted using the *--output-format=parseable* option.